# Replace references storage with std::shared_ptr and std::weak_ptr

Tags: c++

I have a simple case where I know things can go wrong if I start to use threads. [Godbolt here](https://godbolt.org/z/4eqaYa)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class team;

class member
{
    public:
    member(team& my_team) : my_team(my_team) {
        std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl;
    }

    ~member(){
        std::cout << "dtor" << std::endl;
    }

    void modify_my_team()
    {
        //here I want to make sure team is still a valid reference
    }

    private:
    team& my_team;
};

class team
{
    member m1{*this};
    member m2{*this};
    member m3{*this};
};

int main()
{
    team t;
    return 0;
}
```

1. In this example, I want to remove the reference to `team` in the `member` class, in order to avoid the dangling references problem. I think I could use std::shared_ptr and std::weak_ptr. What's the safest way to do this?
2. Is it always bad to store a reference?

Comment: In this particular case, the team will always outlive its members. There is no problem so long as you can guarantee that.

Comment: @molbdnilo in this particular case, yes. But what if one uses `member` in another way than the current `team` class does, which generates a dangling reference?

Comment: What are the chances that that's going to happen? "What if" programming often leads to pointlessly convoluted messes.

Comment: You probably want to mark as deleted some special members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example won't break if you add threads (well, no more than any other solution). As long as you protect access to `team` correctly, it will be fine.

Changing reference to `std::shared_ptr`/`std::weak_ptr` would be problematic. You will need some sort of `initialize()` function in `team`, which will be called manually after its constructor and assigns the weak pointers in `member`s. This is because `shared_from_this()` cannot be used inside constructor.

Using reference as member is not always bad, but some people will frown upon it. In general, as long as you can make sure the reference is valid for the whole lifetime of class, it is safe.
In this case, it seems that `team` and `member` are connected with [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) relation , i.e. `member` can only exist within a `team`. In such a design, reference member is fine.